# Screen goes black on mouse click

Tags: html, iframe, lightbox

I am running a site through EE 1.7.1, using multi-site manager [here](http://www.stonewatercc.com/).  When the page is opened in any browser other than Internet Explorer, it works fine.  When opened in IE 9 or 10 (I haven't tested earlier versions), however, the screen goes black if you click anywhere on it, and will come back on the second click.  The only thing that doesn't go black is the embedded video, and if you click the video, the screen won't go black.

The site with the problem is set up as the main site for the multi-site manager, and the sub-sites don't have this issue.

I've tried looking around for a solution to this problem, but I haven't come up with anything so far.

The code for the video is

```
 <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NVKEqg_l0ls" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and was taken straight from YouTube's embed link.

I don't think that the video code is what is causing this issue, though, since the problem occurs on every page in the site.

Comment: Hello again lucky.hooligan!  I don't believe is not really an EE issue.  Try removing lightbox.js and seeing if the problem goes away.  The black screen is a div with id="overlay" triggered methinks by lightbox.js  If you are still having trouble think you should re-ask on SO and delete this question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of lightbox.js you are running appears to be 5 years old.

Consider updating to a newer version http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Thanks for the help.  IE apparently decided that anywhere on the screen you click, that item was a lightbox.  Unfortunately, I didn't add the lightbox so it didn't occur to me to check it.

Comment: Is there a way to move this question to the normal SO site without deleting it?  I didn't realize that it was a normal issue and not one associated with EE

Comment: I think only a moderator can do that.  I'll flag it.

Comment: Done. It wasn't a huge deal, but I've migrated it for you anyway.